# Count number of distinct combinations across multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server, count, concatenation

Multiple flavors of this question have been asked, but I was not able to find a twist to what I am trying to do. This is my original table (sqlServer):

```
State  City           Job
CA     LOS ANGELES    DEVELOPER
CA     SAN FRANCISCO  DESIGNER
CA     LOS ANGELES    DESIGNER
NY     NEW YORK       DEVELOPER
```

I would like to count the distinct combinations of State and City and return it as a new column in the table. So the final product looks like:

```
State  City           Job         # of Unique
CA     LOS ANGELES    DEVELOPER   3
CA     SAN FRANCISCO  DESIGNER    3
CA     LOS ANGELES    DESIGNER    3
NY     NEW YORK       DEVELOPER   3
```

I tried doing a inner join with the same table and using a count, but that is not returning correct results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your output doesn't match the input. are you expecting 2 for CA - Los Angeles and 1 for the other two rows here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query;

Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (State nvarchar(2), City nvarchar(20), Job nvarchar(20))
INSERT INTO #TestData
VALUES
 ('CA','LOS ANGELES','DEVELOPER')
,('CA','SAN FRANCISCO','DESIGNER')
,('CA','LOS ANGELES','DESIGNER')
,('NY','NEW YORK','DEVELOPER')
```

Query

```
SELECT
     a.State
    ,a.City
    ,a.Job
    ,b.CountField
FROM #TestData a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 
            COUNT(DISTINCT State + City) CountField
            FROM #TestData
            ) b
```

Output (unordered because no order by statement)

```
State   City            Job         CountField
CA      LOS ANGELES     DEVELOPER   3
CA      LOS ANGELES     DESIGNER    3
CA      SAN FRANCISCO   DESIGNER    3
NY      NEW YORK        DEVELOPER   3
```

As per your question in the comments, you can do this to filter for only CA in the count;

```
SELECT
     a.State
    ,a.City
    ,a.Job
    ,b.CountField
FROM #TestData a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 
            COUNT(DISTINCT State + City) CountField
            FROM #TestData
            WHERE State = 'CA'
            ) b
```

Which should output

```
State   City            Job         CountField
CA      LOS ANGELES     DEVELOPER   2
CA      LOS ANGELES     DESIGNER    2
CA      SAN FRANCISCO   DESIGNER    2
NY      NEW YORK        DEVELOPER   2
```

Comment: Thanks Rich, but under the CountField I am hoping to show the total number of unique combinations of state and city repeated every row. So my example, the unique combinations are CA - LA / CA-SANFRAN / NY - NY, so that count column would return 3 on every row. does that make sense?

Comment: @rafacardosoc aah, gotcha. Try that one

Comment: thanks Rich, I marked your response as correct but had a last caviat to ask. Would this query allow me to filter on a state or city and the count would update? So example, if i do a where state = CA, instead of the table outputing 3 every row, it would show 2 as it excludes NY.

Comment: You could do that where clause within the subquery, sure. Just filtering the subquery would leave you with the same number of rows, it'll just count less of them. you'd need to put a where clause in the outer query to reduce your number of rows. If you want to do both then it's going to be two where clauses (one in the inner query and one in the outer). I've just updated the answer to show you.

Comment: Really appreciate all your help and such a speedy response. Happy holidays.